# Openlayers Marker z-index

Tags: openlayers-2, markers, z-index

I have multiple marker in one layer `OpenLayers.Layer.Marker` and some times the marker overlap the other marker. My question is how do I bring the marker in front when its click? is there a `setZ-index` function or some like this in Openlayers?!

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation there is no z-index for OpenLayers Markers, but you can definitely use one on vector layers.

If you had a vector in a variable that you called *someVector*, then you would set it like this:

```
someVector.setZIndex(5);
```

Therefore I would suggest you display your data as a point vector instead of a marker.

Comment: I try this but all the marker send to top. i want the selected marker only to send on top example the `markers[0].marker` set the index to 5 and `markers[1].marker`set index to 4 and the rest is below 5. i just want to arrange the z-index of may markers layer

Comment: Are you using a vector layer now? Not sure, after reading your post above. If the z-index is applied to the entire layer then I would suggest extracting the one marker (the one that you click). Then throw that marker into a separate vector with a higher z-index; that vector would only be used to display the clicked marker.

Comment: Nice idea I will try this. I will duplicate the selected marker into another layer that has a higher index then delete if not selected or delete if select a new marker then duplicate the new one. TY :)

Answer (score 1):

Like user British steel already mentioned I would use a vector layer. Sometimes you also need a redraw of the vector layer.Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883142/change-z-index-of-marker-in-openlayers

Comment: Sorry but im not using vector layer as marker i use `OpenLayers.Layer.Marker` marker layer

Comment: Yes that's the problem ;-) just switch to a vector layer to draw your markers as point features and then you can set the z-index